# Why my query does not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

this is my query :

```
SELECT [MsgType],sr.ServiceName,content,COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
 FROM [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].[ReceiveBuffer] rb
   INNER JOIN dbo.Services sr ON rb.ServiceCode=sr.Code
 where MsgType is not null and MsgType = 2
 group by MsgType,CONTEnt, sr.ServiceName
 order by COUNT(*) DESC

UNION

SELECT [MsgType],sr.ServiceName,content,COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
 FROM [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].ReceivedSMS rb
   INNER JOIN dbo.Services sr ON rb.ServiceCode=sr.Code
where MsgType is not null and MsgType = 2
group by MsgType,CONTEnt, sr.ServiceName
order by COUNT(*) DESC
```

sql give me this error :`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'` ! what is the problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Seems like a pretty extensive query?

Comment: you can't have an `ORDER BY` clause before the `UNION` keyword

Comment: @JohnWoo how can use UNION in this query?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard `[...]` quoting style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments about the query:

- You probably want `union all` and not `union`.  If two rows happen to have exactly the same three fields, I doubt you want to remove one of them.
- Your `where` clause is redundant.

(This is in addition to the `order by` problem.)

```
SELECT [MsgType], sr.ServiceName, content, COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
FROM [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].[ReceiveBuffer] rb INNER JOIN
     dbo.Services sr
     ON rb.ServiceCode =s r.Code
where MsgType = 2
group by content, sr.ServiceName
UNION ALL
SELECT [MsgType], sr.ServiceName, content, COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
FROM [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].ReceivedSMS rb INNER JOIN
      dbo.Services sr
      ON rb.ServiceCode = sr.Code
where MsgType = 2
group by MsgType, content, sr.ServiceName
order by Occurrence DESC;
```

Note that this will give you multiple rows.  If you want an overall count, then do the `union all` before the aggregation:

```
SELECT MsgType, sr.ServiceName, content, COUNT(*) AS Occurrence
FROM (select msgtype, servicecode, content
      from [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].[ReceiveBuffer] rb 
      where MsgType = 2
      union all
      select
      from  [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].ReceivedSMS rb
      where MsgType = 2
     ) rb INNER JOIN
     dbo.Services sr
     ON rb.ServiceCode = sr.Code
group by MsgType, content, sr.ServiceName
order by Occurrence DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an ORDER BY clause before the UNION keyword.

If you want to order by record set as well as COUNT(*) you can add a column like this:

```
SELECT [MsgType],sr.ServiceName,content,COUNT(*) AS Occurrence, 1 AS recordset_order
 FROM [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].[ReceiveBuffer] rb
   INNER JOIN dbo.Services sr ON rb.ServiceCode=sr.Code
 where MsgType is not null and MsgType = 2
 group by MsgType,CONTEnt, sr.ServiceName
UNION
SELECT [MsgType],sr.ServiceName,content,COUNT(*) AS Occurrence, 2 AS recordset_order
 FROM [VSReceiveSend].[dbo].ReceivedSMS rb
   INNER JOIN dbo.Services sr ON rb.ServiceCode=sr.Code
where MsgType is not null and MsgType = 2
group by MsgType,CONTEnt, sr.ServiceName
order by recordset_order ASC, COUNT(*) DESC
```